# Showing a modal dialog box or form when the application is not running in UserInteractive mode is not a valid operation

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-applications

I encounter this error when I want to read a .xlsx excel file on my remote server but strangely not on my local machine. I've tried changing my codes from **MessageBox.Show(mymessage)** to
**ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "myalert", "alert('" + mymessage+ "');", true);**

Then I realised that even if I comment out all the display messages msgbox/alert, I'd still face the same error.

> **Source Error:** An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
>
> **Stack Trace**
>   [InvalidOperationException: Showing a modal dialog box or form when the application is not running in UserInteractive mode is not a valid operation. Specify the ServiceNotification or DefaultDesktopOnly style to display a notification from a service application.]
>      System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.ShowCore(IWin32Window owner, String text, String caption, MessageBoxButtons buttons, MessageBoxIcon icon, MessageBoxDefaultButton defaultButton, MessageBoxOptions options, Boolean showHelp) +2661826
>      System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(String text, String caption, MessageBoxButtons buttons, MessageBoxIcon icon, MessageBoxDefaultButton defaultButton) +25
>      NetWorkInformationSystem.classes.ReadExcelFile.GetDataFromExcelPatchRecordRead(String filename) in C:\Documents and Settings\yeohs\Desktop\NetWorkInformationSystem\NetWorkInformationSystem\classes\ReadExcelFile.cs:62
>      NetWorkInformationSystem.PatchRecords.ConfirmBtn_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Documents and Settings\yeohs\Desktop\NetWorkInformationSystem\NetWorkInformationSystem\forms\PatchRecords.aspx.cs:121
>      System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e) +111
>      System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +110
>      System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +10
>      System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler sourceControl, String eventArgument) +13
>      System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection postData) +36
>      System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +1565

```
listofTableTable = ReadExcelFile.GetDataFromExcelPatchRecordRead(filename);
listofDataSet = ReadListOfDataFromExcelPatchRecord(listofTableTable);

    if (listofDataSet.Count >= 1)
    {
    //insert according by filename
    int deletecount = GICdatabase.InsertRecords(listofDataSet);
}
```

**Read Records**

```
    foreach (DataRow dr in listofTableTable.Rows)
{
string a= dr["a"].ToString().ToUpper().Trim();
string b= dr["b"].ToString().ToUpper().Trim();
string c= dr["c"].ToString().ToUpper().Trim();
string d= dr["d"].ToString().ToUpper().Trim();
string e= dr["e"].ToString().Trim();
string f= dr["f"].ToString().ToUpper().Trim();
string g= dr["g"].ToString().ToLower().Trim();
string h= dr["h"].ToString().ToLower().Trim();
string i= dr["i"].ToString().ToLower().Trim();
string j= dr["j"].ToString().ToLower().Trim();
DateTime datestamp =DateTime.Now.ToLocalTime();
}
```

**

> HEY PROS!! ANY GREAT SOLUTION TO DISPLAY OPTION MESSAGE BOX ON SERVER
>   TO PROVIDE?  e.g OK,CANCEL? YES,NO?

**

Comment: the error is related to the way you are reading the .xlsx file. posting that code could be helpful.

Comment: hey thanks for replying, but i find it weird! y didnt it display the message on the remote server but its totally fine on local machine. I've got some other problems like the displaying of username(UserPrincipal.Current.DisplayName) and exporting a excel template as well. but now i jus wanna solve this problem...

Comment: in the original error, it talks about a stack trace..do you have that?

Comment: hey, yea! jus edited. what do you think could be the cause?

Comment: one issue might be you are trying to use MessageBox.Show() in the web code. This is win-forms way of showing messages and cannot do it this way in web. And you have said even if you comment that out, you still get the same error? Is it having the same stack trace? (I doubt)

Comment: heyhey! i realise if i remove the **using System.Windows.Forms** i will not see that error again! but the data that is supposed to be read is not added into the database! What could be the cause now?

Answer (score 0):

So to summarize what happened through comments,

> hey, yea! jus edited. what do you think could be the cause?

one issue might be you are trying to use MessageBox.Show() in the web
 code. This is win-forms way of showing messages and cannot do it this
 way in web.

> but the data that is supposed to be read is not added into the database! What could be the 
>   cause now?

This one you need to debug and see what happens in the `GICdatabase.InsertRecords(listofDataSet);`

**Note** : It looks like you are going about implementing a web application in the wrong way ( win-forms strategies) which is not correct. I suggest you read some asp.net articles and understand the fundamental differences first.